# GCC have include but not library

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system, glibc, libc

I'm writing my own kernel for fun, and in doing so I've needed to install `glibc` to use the standard C libraries. However, after installing the library to the desired directory, my kernel.c program includes the `stdio.h` header and attempts to use `fopen`, however I come across this error:

`kernel.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to`fopen'`

After looking around I noticed that I don't have any actual code to all of the header files, just the header files themselves. So I went and added the `-L` flag to GCC to add the `lib` folder that was created during the compilation of `glibc` and what I've found out is that the `lib` folder has nothing of what I need.

I poked around and found that the `build` directory I used when compiling `glibc` has the `.o` files I'm looking for (e.g it has `iofopen.o` for the `fopen` method).

So what's going on?

If needed, the commands I am using to compile my kernel are:

```
#!/bin/bash
nasm -felf32 boot.asm -o boot.o
/home/noah/opt/cross/bin/i686-elf-gcc -I/home/noah/Documents/NoahOS/include/ -L/home/noah/Documents/glibc/build  -c *.c -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra
/home/noah/opt/cross/bin/i686-elf-gcc -I/home/noah/Documents/NoahOS/include/ -L/home/noah/Documents/glibc/build -T linker.ld -o noahos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib *.o -lgcc
```

First line builds the `boot` file, which is assembly.
Second line runs `gcc` on all of the C language `.c` files and creates their object files.
Third line links all of the files together with `linker.ld` and outputs the final kernel to `noahos.bin` which is a runnable kernel using

`qemu-system-i386 -kernel noahos.bin`

If needed more information can be provided. Please ask.

Comment: You removed `stdlib` with `-nostdlib` option, if you do so you must give an implementation of the functions you've used. Remove that option, or add `-lc`. There is no code in header files, as that would cause multiple definitions of functions.

Answer (score 3):

You are correctly compiling your kernel using `-nostdlib` because the kernel can't use the standard library.  Why not? Because it doesn't make sense: the standard library is the interface between user programs and the kernel, so that application developers don't need to know the system call specification for your kernel, all that is required is a port of the C library.

Oh, there's the answer.  You need a *port* of the C library to use your own system calls.  Starting with glibc might not be the easiest to port (it comes with the kitchen sink).

Comment: You can't use `libc` stdio *inside* your custom kernel, even if you ported glibc to your custom-kernel's system call API/ABI.  You could use it for its implementation of any function that doesn't make system calls, though, like `sprintf`, `strtol`, `memcpy`, and any other useful functions with nice optimized implementations.